# Como agrupar uma coluna que contém uma lista no pandas? - Python3

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Fala galera!
Estou com um problema no pandas que não conseguir achar uma solução.
Eu tenho o seguinte dataset:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria fazer uma agrupação onde, para cada ano, e em cada categoria presente naquele ano, ele somasse os votos de cada uma dessas categorias.

Nesse exemplo o output seria algo do tipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema que sempre quando eu chamo o .groupby tentando passar o genres ele me da o erro TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Uma coisa que tenho é uma lista com todos os generos existentes no dataframe, não sei se vai ajudar

Aqui o cód q estou usando. O dataset mencionado é obtido do qtdgeneroyearv2

```
qtdgeneroyearv2 = pd.DataFrame(dataframefilmes) 
qtdgeneroyearv2[['genres', 'year', 'votes']].groupby(['year', 'genres']).sum()
```

Alguém para me dar um luz? Obrigado!

Comment: Olá viva, precisas de partilhar mais dados, o código que estás a utilizar...só duas tabelas não chega...contudo, dá uma vista de olhos neste tópico que pode ajudar-te.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby

Comment: Oi Ernesto. Obrigado pela resposta. O tópico enviado é diferente pois ele pega o dado agrupa em lista. E oq eu preciso fazer é o contrario; pegar oq está em uma lista e agregar.

Comment: O código que estou usando é bastante simples, por isso nao achei que fazia muito sentido colocar, mas aqui está: 
qtdgeneroyearv2 = pd.DataFrame(dataframefilmes)
qtdgeneroyearv2[['genres', 'year', 'votes']].groupby(['year', 'genres']).sum()
Daí obtenho : unhashable type: 'list'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o metodo [explode() do pandas 0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/reshaping.html#exploding-a-list-like-column) , para seu caso:

```
qtdgeneroyearv2.explode('genres')
```

aplicando o explode e  depois o agrupamento:

```
qtdgeneroyearv2.explode('genres')[['genres', 'year', 'votes']].groupby(['year', 'genres']).sum()
```

saida:

```
year  genres           
2016  Family      votes      25
      Game-Show   votes      25
      Music       votes      25
      Reality-TV  votes      25
2018  Comedy      votes    None
      Drama       votes      39
2019  Comedy      votes      16
2020  Comedy      votes    None
dtype: object
```

Comment: FUNCIONOU AMIGO! Tu me explodiu de alegria aqui hahaha. Muitíssimo obrigado